# Assigning Firestore filed to a variable, and display it in HTML-Angualr 7

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to assign a specific field in firestore to a variable in Angular.

Specifically, I am trying to get the filed "Annual', and display it in HTML.

[image]

This is the code which I tried:

```
AnnualVacationRef = this.firestore.collection('vacationBalance').doc('B2TKfIoz1jrJJ954jZ9z.Annual');
```

In HTML:

```
<h3>Annual Vacations: {{AnnualVacationRef.Annual}}</h3>
```

However, nothing is displayed.

Appreciate your assistance.

Comment: are you using [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)? what is `this.firestore`?

Comment: I am using angular 7. Angular Firstore is imported as below: import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

Comment: Then you are indeed using angularfire2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are halfway right. 
However, you don't put `.Annual` to the document id:

```
const document = this.firestore.collection('vacationBalance').doc('B2TKfIoz1jrJJ954jZ9z')
```

But you also need to use the `.get()` method to obtain the `DocumentSnapshot`:

```
const snapshot: Obervable<firestore.DocumentSnapshot> = this.firestore.collection('vacationBalance').doc('B2TKfIoz1jrJJ954jZ9z').get()
```

As you can see in the return type you will get an Observable. Now you have two options to get the value: `subscribe` or `pipe(map(...))`

**Subscribe**

```
this.fireStore.collection('collectionname').doc(id).get().subscribe(value => {
  const data = value.data();
  console.log(data);
  item = data;
});
```

**Pipe(Map(...))**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

item = this.fireStore.collection('collectionname').doc(id).get().pipe(map(
  (value: firestore.DocumentSnapshot) => {
    return value.data();
  }
));
```

`.data` always return the whole document. 
The result should look like this:

> { 'Annual': 14 }

**Html:**

```
<p>Annual: {{item?.Annual}}</p>
```

Comment: Good morning Jens...Many thanks for your support. The subscribe really made it working...Have a nice day